# c++ compiling error with terminal

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

I wrote a piece of code with xcode 7.2 on a mac which compiles and works fine. However when i try to compile from terminal with command `g++ -std=c++11 -o main.cpp` an error occurs `undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`
`functionname(std::_1::basic_istream<char,std::_1::char_traits<char> >&)"`

where `functionname` is a function I created that has a file stream as a parameter.I am new to these kinds of compiling errors, so help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is that function defined in main.cpp, or in some other file? If it's in a different file, you have to also compile that file on the same command line.

Comment: its in another file, and I think thats the problem! thanks.